# SQL: querying the max of sum written either as subquery or CTE fails

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, common-table-expression

Assume a table *salaries* that contains *employee_id*, *department_id* and *salary*, as follows.

```
e_id | dpt_id | salary
---- | ------ | ------
   1 |      2 |   1000
   2 |      2 |   2000
   3 |      5 |   3000
   4 |      6 |    500
   5 |      5 |    100
   6 |      1 |   1050
```

I wanted to bring the dpt with the maximum/minimum salaries and I used the following query which failed:

```sql
select sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id, max(sum_sal_per_dpt.total_salaries)
from (
      select dpt_id, sum(salary) as total_salaries
      from salaries
      group by dpt_id ) as sum_sal_per_dpt
group by sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id
union
select sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id, min(sum_sal_per_dpt.total_salaries)
from (
      select dpt_id, sum(salary) as total_salaries
      from salaries
      group by dpt_id ) as sum_sal_per_dpt
group by sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id
```

The output I get is a table with the dpt_id and the summation of salaries, as if the subquery is only executed:

```
dpt_id | salary
------ | ------
     2 |   3000
     5 |   3100
     6 |    500
     1 |   1050
```

instead of

```
dpt_id | salary
------ | ------
     5 |   3100
     6 |    500
```

Same if I write it in a CTE fashion.

```
with
sum_sal_per_dpt as (select dpt_id, sum(salary) as total_salaries
                    from salaries
                    group by dpt_id)
select sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id, max(sum_sal_per_dpt.total_salaries)
from sum_sal_per_dpt
group by sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id
union
select sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id, min(sum_sal_per_dpt.total_salaries)
from sum_sal_per_dpt
group by sum_sal_per_dpt.dpt_id
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: If you group by dpt, you get one result row per dpt. If you group this result again by dpt, you still have one result row per dpt. That means the second time you group by dpt, you are actually not aggregating at all. in The first pass you get the total salary per dpt. In the second pass you get the maximum total salary per dpt. As thewre is only one total salary per dtp, the maximum of that one value is the value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should give you the results you expect:

```
;with data as
(
select dpt_id, sum(salary) as total_salaries
from salaries
group by dpt_id
)
select dpt_id, total_salaries
from data 
where total_salaries = (select max(total_salaries) from data)
union 
select dpt_id, total_salaries
from data 
where total_salaries = (select min(total_salaries) from data)
```

Note that the above code will give you multiple rows if you have multiple max and/or min values, you can easily adjust this depending on what you want to see.

Within your code, you were using group by `dpt_id`, which is why you were still getting max values per `dpt_id`, hence multiple rows, additional confusion might have been created with using `union` instead of `union all`, which would remove the rows that are the same in both tables.

Answer (score 3):

Essentialy the same answer as from Boris Jovanovic, just without an union.

```
with
sum_sal_per_dpt as (select dpt_id, sum(salary) as total_salaries
                    from salaries
                    group by dpt_id)

SELECT dpt_id, total_salaries
FROM sum_sal_per_dpt
WHERE 
total_salaries = ( SELECT max(total_salaries) FROM sum_sal_per_dpt )
OR 
total_salaries = ( SELECT min(total_salaries) FROM sum_sal_per_dpt );
```

Result:

| dpt_id | total_salaries |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 3100 |
| 6 | 500 |

Example on [DB-Fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/URLq1LUz)

##### Why your inital queries don't work:

You always fall back to using "GROUP BY" and instruct the DBMS to aggregate your results by the dpt_id.
So it will never sort out any department id.

*Max(XYZ)* isn't a filter/aggregate function to only give you the maximal value of a column and all corresponding fields to this maximum value.
It will give you the maximal value for every distinct row - whereby distinction is defined by the columns you refer to in the *GROUP BY clause*

If you change the first query to just give out the Max/Min Values, you can see that the values are already there - just unusable.

```sql
select max(sum_sal_per_dpt.total_salaries), min(sum_sal_per_dpt.total_salaries)
from (
      select dpt_id, sum(salary) as total_salaries
      from salaries
      group by dpt_id ) as sum_sal_per_dpt
```

| max | min |
| --- | --- |
| 3100 | 500 |

I just then applied the solution for this problem from the aggergate tutorial from the official postgres documentation.
[Postgres Documentation for aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows. Then filtering is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select dpt_id, sum(salary) as ts,
    row_number() over(order by sum(salary)) as rn,
    row_number() over(order by sum(salary) desc) as rnd
  from t
  group by dpt_id
) x
where rn = 1 or rnd = 1
```

Result:

```
 dpt_id  ts    rn  rnd 
 ------- ----- --- --- 
 6       500   1   4   
 5       3100  4   1
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ajqrhQCo).